# WP use string as name of control

Tags: vb.net, string, controls

Please, can anyone help me with this problem:
I have a name(s) of control(s) in string format (`str`) and I want to set property (in code) of that controls using that string-name.

I try something like this but it doesn't work. Actually, I have a problem with expression. When I put exactly the name it works but when i use variable in string format it doesn't.

```
Dim str as String
str="k3"
Dim g As Image = CType(str, Image)
g.Source = New BitmapImage(New Uri("/APP;component/Icons/hero.png", UriKind.Relative))
```

This works:

```
Dim g As Image = CType(k3, Image)
```

While this does not:

```
Dim g As Image = CType(str, Image)
```

Comment: You can't expect a `String` to be an `Image`.

Comment: Yes, that's right, but String can be a name of image control.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are trying to do, to declare an object by a string...

Essentially for this to work you will need a custom function that returns the Object Type that you are seeking...

You will need to loop through each control and check the name of the control as a comparison, e.g. If oControl.Name.ToString = sString then Return oControl

Example

```
' A function to return a Control by the Control's name...
Public Function GetControlByName(ByVal oForm As Form, ByVal sName As String) As Control

    Dim cReturn As New Control
    Dim ctrl As Control

    For Each ctrl In oForm.Controls
        cReturn = ctrl
        If ctrl.Name.ToString = sName Then
            Return ctrl ' this is what we want!
        End If

    Next

    Return cReturn
End Function



' Example Usage

Dim oButton As Button = GetControlByName(Me, "Button44")

If oButton.Name.ToString = "Button44" Then

  MessageBox.Show("I have found your Button!")

Else

  MessageBox.Show("Your button was NOT Found!")

End If
```

Obviously there is room for error with this function, because if sName is NOT found, then it will return the last ctrl found, therefore, you will need to ensure that the control you seek is indeed found, via the If statement as provided in the example above...

Furthermore, it may not loop through controls inside of containers, menus, etc, but I'm not sure on that, so you will need to check to ensure it's not having that problem...

(The Me in the statement will most likely be used more often than not, though Me could be the name of the form you are searching if you are running the code outside of the form you are searching the form with the function.)

FINALLY, to answer your question, you will need to change Control to Image, and Set CReturn as a New Image, and then use Return ctrl.BackgroundImage   (etc) to return the image..

Comment: I think functions like this should return `Nothing` if nothing is found - similar to `TryCast`.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I do not think that you understand the question. To simplify: I already have a (many) controls (image) on screen, I know its names and just because i have it a lot, want to set property from code by its name (which is every time different from previous one).

Comment: OK, I went back and read what you are doing, still a bit confused, but I think essentially you are wanting to store data (the location of the image) somewhere in the control or the image itself?

Also, above you said (str,...) wouldn't work, but str isn't defined!!!

Or is it that you wish to retrieve the image with str?

Comment: I put "on screen" because app is for windows phone. It is not windows app with forms. But thank you anyway for your time.

Comment: This works just fine: RealNameofImageControl.Source = New BitmapImage ...  But i want instead of "RealNameOfImageControl" to use string variable. For example "strVariable" which has some string value.

Comment: can you plainly tell me why you want to do this?

Comment: I have 28 image controls on form. So, I want to make a loop and update image control property using string (which is actually name of the control).